# Mercurial revision checkout is working, but according to the log, the revision is not exist

Tags: mercurial

I have some issue with Mercurial. The checkout of a revision is working (via hg clone -r X command, which clones the X. revision), but when i tried to get log for the X. revision, it returns with revision not exist. How can i solve this problem?

Commands i use:

```
hg clone -r RevisionNumber /path/to/local/repo my_folder
```

Then:

```
hg log -r RevisionNumber --template 'my_template'
hg diff -c RevisionNumber
```

I get:

```
abort: unknown revision 'RevisionNumber '!
```

I tried revisioning with number, and with number:hash, neither worked.

Comment: Please enter the exact commands you are using. And what is X? The hash, a tag, or the number?

Comment: In your `log` command, remove everything after the first RevNum, and try again.

Comment: Don't use `--template` option, if you don't know how to use it

Comment: The problem isn't with my template tag, i can use it. Without the template tag, the problem still the same.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but you do `cd my_folder` in between the clone and the log, right?

Comment: What happens if you do `hg log -r tip`?

Comment: It said that i have an older revision checkouted (however not)

Comment: That does not make sense. You are querying for the last commit, it does not care where you've updated (checked out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess here is that you are referencing the changeset by the revision id (your `RevisionNumber`) that is local to the original repo. Only the changeset identifying hash is globally unique. I'm basing this guess on your statement

> I tried revisioning with number, and with number:hash, neither worked.

You should try using *only the hash* and see if that works.

```
hg log -r [hash]
```

(If you do `number:hash`, `hg` thinks your are looking for the range of changes between `number` and `hash`.)

Explanation: When you clone to a specific revison, Mercurial only includes changesets that direct ancestors of that revision and leaves out all others. The numbering is locally sequential (meaning new numbers are assigned as the changeset arrives at the repo).

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution